# Ubuntu won't load and I can't access GRUB

Tags: boot, grub2

It shows the loading screen then goes to a black screen with a bunch of lines and the top line says 
[Failed] Failed to start Load/Save Screen Backlight Brightness of backlight:acpi_video1

I tried opening GRUB to boot into recovery mode but GRUB does not open. I triee holding down Shift key on startup, I tried pressing Esc key but nothing works. I don't have anything important on my computer and have a bootable USB but can't access BIOS either to boot from the USB. And I'm stuck right now. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure you can't even access your BIOS? Why is that? I mean you press supr key (or the key for your mobo) and what happens then?

Comment: Well nothing happens

Comment: If UEFI and you left UEFI fast boot on, you do not have time to press a key, as it goes immediately to boot system. Usually you can do a full cold boot not warm reboot to give time to press key to get into UEFI or UEFI boot menu. If laptop also remove battery as system must be fully powered down. Shut down, hold power key for 10 sec or more and then boot and press correct key or keys to get into UEFI.

Comment: funny enough I got that message in my journalctl when trying to chase up the latest freeze. anyhow, for me and grub see this.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1163047/who-is-changing-my-grub-cfg-changes-to-timeout-makes-grub-not-show

Comment: Thank you olfred, I managed to get into BIOS, but when I boot from the USB and try to install Ubuntu it says 'load the kernel first'. I found some solutions for that but the grub ls command doesn't do anything. Could you help please?