# who is changing my grub.cfg? changes to timeout makes grub not show

Tags: grub2, 19.04, amd-ryzen

Here is my audit on changes to the grub config file at /boot/grub/grub.cfg
The change makes the timeout=10 (that I have done to get the grub menu to show at all) to timeout=0 which means grub does not show at all.
I was asleep when this happened.  I am very tempted to make that file read only and see what happens. Ubuntu 19.04,ryzen 5 2500U with vega radeon mobile gfx 2000mhz. default amd drivers (updated yesterday but this is not a new problem for me, happens every update grub). Any ideas on why this is happening at all? (apart from conspiracy theories). The change timestamp on the file is also 6.07am, when I was sound asleep.

> 33. 2019-08-03 06:07:23 /boot/grub/ unlinkat no /usr/bin/rm unset 303
> 34. 2019-08-03 06:07:23 /boot/grub/grub.cfg.new openat yes /usr/bin/dash unset 304
> 35. 2019-08-03 06:07:23 . openat yes /usr/bin/dash unset 305
> 36. 2019-08-03 06:07:23 . openat yes /usr/bin/dash unset 306
> 37. 2019-08-03 06:07:23 . openat yes /usr/bin/dash unset 307
> 38. 2019-08-03 06:07:23 . openat yes /usr/bin/dash unset 308
> 39. 2019-08-03 06:07:23 . openat yes /usr/bin/dash unset 309
> 40. 2019-08-03 06:07:23 . openat yes /usr/bin/dash unset 310
> 41. 2019-08-03 06:07:23 . openat yes /usr/bin/dash unset 311
> 42. 2019-08-03 06:07:23 . openat yes /usr/bin/dash unset 312
> 43. 2019-08-03 06:07:27 /boot/grub/grub.cfg.new fchmodat yes /usr/bin/chmod unset 314
> 44. 2019-08-03 06:07:27 /boot/grub/grub.cfg.new openat yes /usr/bin/grub-script-check unset 315
> 45. 2019-08-03 06:07:27 /boot/grub/ renameat2 no /usr/bin/mv unset 316
> 46. 2019-08-03 06:07:27 /boot/grub/grub.cfg rename yes /usr/bin/mv unset 317
> 47. 2019-08-03 06:07:27 /boot/grub/grub.cfg.new openat yes /usr/bin/grep unset 313
> 48. 2019-08-03 07:38:06 . openat yes /usr/bin/updatedb.mlocate unset 346
> 49. 2019-08-03 12:48:37 /boot/grub sendto yes /usr/sbin/auditctl unset 54
> 50. 2019-08-03 12:48:37 /boot/grub/grubenv openat yes /usr/bin/grub-editenv unset 77
> 51. 2019-08-03 12:48:37 /boot/grub/grubenv openat yes /usr/bin/grub-editenv unset 78

the relevant part of grub.cfg is

```
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=10
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=10
  fi
fi
```

the problem is when my =10 are changed to =0

the audit was gotten from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/99074/find-which-process-is-modifying-a-file

```
sudo apt auditd
```

then   set up with

```
sudo  auditctl  -w /boot/grub -k grubchanges -p rwxa
```

and reported with

```
sudo ausearch -k grubchanges | aureport -f -i
```

Comment: adding that the computer was not connected to the internet at 6.07am

Comment: Do you have this? `/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new` That is only created if you have a typo in grub scripts or settings files. It could be that grub or a kernel updated in the background, but then could not create new grub.cfg.

Comment: You shouldn't be touching `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`... or even looking at it. The file to edit is `/etc/default/grub`... and the line to edit is `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10`.

Comment: @oldfred no I dont have that file....    not now anyway. and it did modify the grub.cfg at 6.07am , which was my issue. and yet journalctl | grep grub.cfg.new turns up  03 14:57:54 ....: PATH item=0 name="/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new"   the filename is in red, - that was me updating grub per the answer below, and yet the file grub.cfg.new is not there in that directory, perhaps it was temporary and deleted.

Comment: @heynnema thanks, I had to vote for the official answer below though, put in place in the same hour as yours. edut grub, update-grub worked and shows in grub.cfg (I havent rebooted yet though)

Answer (score 4):

The answer is obvious: it is changed by `grub-mkconfig`. If you change `grub.cfg` manually, all changes will be overwritten on the next `update-grub`.

Grub is updated on every kernel upgrade and also in other cases.

Instead of changing `grub.cfg` edit `/etc/default/grub` and run `sudo update-grub`.

You can read this in the beginning of `grub.cfg`.

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#
```

Comment: I need to learn how to read..... thanks. mind you, it is still a mystery to me as to why  timeout=0 for my machine is supposed to be a good thing. it works hand in hand - no grub menu - with blank screens on bootup that is a common issue people have  with amd.. noting that there is also a generated (do not edit warning) file cat grub.radeon.bak that has GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.modeset=0
 in it. I do not have that line in my grub.